# Whine emanating from soundsystem, independent of volume, on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, motherboard, sound-card, speakers

When ever I plug in my headphones in to my computer's headphone jack, on Ubuntu, I get a constant whine that is independent of volume or any other modification I make on alsamixer. I do not have a mic plugged in.

The sound quality itself is good enough, but the whine starts as soon as Ubuntu begins, even before I have logged in. 
I have determined that the sound card is not the issue as I have a dual boot system with Windows 7, and when I log onto Windows, no such noise is heard, the headphones work perfect.

My specs are:
AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1100T Processor × 6, 64 bit.
8 gig ram,
Mobo: Asus M4a88td-V Evo

OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with the latest patches/updates from canonical

I cant seem to find anything on Asus' website that would solve this 
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a bug in the driver you are using.  Upgrade to the latest version.  This could also be indications of a hardware or software incompatibility of one or more devices/drivers with your sound card/driver.  Could be a bug in a driver that is causing bad things to happen with your sound card.

Based on what you have provided here that is about all anybody could consider.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might have been caused by some electronic interference/bad shielding -

My headphone Jack is next to some USB ports, and I had plugged a logitech webcam into a port- that was the cause of the whine- the moment it was out, the whine went away!

Plug it in and it returns.